# Zoom image keeping the center fix with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an script that will resize an image with a jquery slider. The image is inside an    overflow hidden conatiner. But I am getting problem in keeping the center of the image fix while zooming out or in. I know that can be done by plus minus the left and top value while zooming in out. But can't able to find a way to do it. You can View my script-

```
var globalElement_width;
var globalElement_height;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $img=$('.canvas img');
   globalElement_width=$img.width();
   globalElement_height=$img.height();

   $( ".slider" ).slider({
       step: 1, 
       min: 0,
       max: 100,
       value: 0,
       slide: function( event, ui )
       {
        resize_img(ui.value);
       }
  });

  $('.canvas img').draggable();

});
function resize_img(val)
{
    var width=globalElement_width;
    var zoom_percen=width * 0.5; // Maximum zoom 50%
    var ASPECT = zoom_percen / 50;
    var zoom_value = val / 2;
    var size= width + ASPECT * zoom_value;

    $img = $('.canvas img');
    $img.stop(true).animate({
        width: size
    }, 250);
}
```

Jsfiddle-

http://jsfiddle.net/hirenbg89/Qv35B/5/

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change `margin-top` and `margin-left` by half of the shift value:

```
var d = ASPECT*zoom_value/2;
$img.stop(true).animate({
    marginTop: -d,
    marginLeft: -d,
    width: size
}, 250);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/Qv35B/6/

Comment: It is working great with fix center. But can we do it using left and top values as I have to add an containment in the draggable element. For that I need the dynamically changing top, right values. Thanks again.

Comment: Just change `marginTop` to `top` and `marginLeft` to `left` and it will work either.

Comment: Yes, that will work either. But if I try to resize it after drag it to any other position it will jump to a wrong position. I want to resize it anywhere in the box without using margin. Can you provide me any suggestion .

Comment: Ok, I did it like this-

    `var d = ASPECT*zoom_value/2;`
    `var setTop=$img.position().top - d;`
    `var setLeft=$img.position().left - d;` 

    `$img.stop(true).animate({`
         `top: -setTop,`
         `left: -setleft,`
         `width: size`
    `}, 250);`

But the image is still jumping for zooming in/out of dragged image

Comment: can I have some help. @dfsq